# Baixar várias páginas com curl no mesmo endereço sem sobrescrever

Tags: loop, libcurl, bash

Preciso baixar essa página várias vezes, ela retorna um resultado diferente cada vez que é acessada:

```
i="0"

while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
    curl -O http://httpbin.org/bytes/128
    i=$[$i+1]
done
```

Mas cada vez que o comando curl é executado, o arquivo anterior é sobrescrito, já que o nome é igual.

Como faço para não sobrescrever? Os nomes poderiam ser sequenciais ex. "128 (1)", "128 (2)", ..., "128 (n)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a opção `-o` (o minúsculo) para especificar onde escrever a resposta e utilize o seu contador como nome do arquivo:

```
i=0; 
while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do 
    curl http://httpbin.org/bytes/128 -o 128_$i
    i=$[$i+1]
done
```

Ou mais claramente usando `for`:

```
for i in {1..10}; do 
    curl http://httpbin.org/bytes/128 -o 128_$i
done
```

Ou mais dahoramente usando `seq`:

```
seq -f 'curl http://httpbin.org/bytes/128 -o 128_%g' 9 | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, bom o curl pode ser usado com o -o para setar um arquivo para output, como explicaram no stack overflow internacional: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735051/capture-curl-output-to-a-file

> curl -K myconfig.txt -o output.txt
>
> Writes the first output received in the file you specify (overwrites if an old one exists).
>
> curl -K myconfig.txt >> output.txt
>
> Appends all output you receive to the specified file.

Assim você pode usar a variável declarada para nomear os arquivos.